# Query all issues with a fixVersion = next non-released version in Jira

Tags: jira

I would like to create a query that returns issues based on a version type field that is equivalent to the next unreleased version on a particular number branch sequence.

For example:

```
fixVersion IN ('1.7.1')
```

would give me all of the issues where the fixVersion is set as 1.7.1

What I would like to do is be able to create a query that selects the next unreleased version in the 1.7 branch

For example:

```
fixVersion IN (NextUnreleasedVersion)
```

In addition I would like to get a version that is the last released version in a similar manner.

Is it possible to do this with the standard Jira query mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with standard JQL. You could try a custom JQL function with Script Runner

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
fixVersion in earliestUnreleasedVersionByReleaseDate([projectkey])
```

See [Jira documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-earliestUnreleasedVersionearliestUnreleasedVersion())

Comment: Which version was this introduced in?

Comment: I don't know, it was is in google searches dating 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sprints (greenhopper), I found there's an openSprints() function that helps you get what you want:

```
assignee = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved AND sprint in openSprints() 
   ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
```

Doesn't help with the fixVersion unfortunately. In that case, we've usually had a couple backlog versions to just exclude, and I've usually used something like this:

```
assignee = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved AND 
  fixVersion not in ("Feature Backlog", "Bug Backlog") ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
```